# Is this piecewise function a continuous bijection but not homeomorphic?

Tags: general-topology, functions, continuity

This is a follow up to a question I asked yesterday regarding a continuous, bijective, but non-homeomorphic function from $(0,1)$ to some set $T \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Consider this piecewise function to represent a "figure 8" shape with $x=1/2$ mapping to the origin. Is this a function with the above properties?
$\DeclareMathOperator{\im}{im}$

Let $f: (0,1) \longrightarrow \im(f)$ be given by:

$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} 
    \bigl(\sin(4\pi{x}),\, 1+\cos(4\pi{x}) \bigr) 
    & x \in (0,\frac{1}{2}] \\
    \bigl(\sin(4\pi{x}),\, \cos(4\pi{x})-1 \bigr) 
    & x \in [\frac{1}{2}, 1) \\
\end{cases}
$$

If so, how would I explicitly describe $\im(f)$?
I think it would be something like:
$$
\im(f) 
    = \bigl\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+(y-1)^2=1 \bigr\} 
    \cup \bigl\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2 : x^2+(y+1)^2=1 \bigr\}
$$

Is this correct?

Comment: As written, $f$ is not continuous (or even well-defined). Notice how the definition of $f$ for $x \in (0, \frac12]$ assigns $f(\frac12) = (0, 2)$. Essentially, you've parametrized the upper circle from the top, but you want to parametrize it from the bottom (the origin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you modify the definition of $f$ so that it's well-defined, say with
$$
f(x) = \bigl( \sin(4\pi x),\, 1 - \cos(4\pi x) \bigr) 
$$
for $x \in (0, \frac12]$,
then **yes** that is a valid description of the continuous image, assuming the standard topology on the interval $(0,1)$ and the subspace topology on $\mathrm{im}(f) \subset \mathbb{R}^2$.

Note that you can always describe such an algebraic set as the *zero set* of a *single* polynomial if you want:
$$
\bigl( x^2 + (y-1)^2 - 1 \bigr) \bigl( x^2 + (y+1)^2 - 1 \bigr). 
$$

Comment: Thank you! I was actually just stuck on the parametrization, so it all makes sense now.

Comment: By the way, you can parametrize different types of these "figure-8" curves in one go if you know the magic word *lemniscate*: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemniscate